# Extracting SSID password from supplicant config file in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I'm trying to write an Android SYSTEM app that extracts the Wifi password from the supplicant configuration file (/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf).

Using adb with root permissions, I can read the file without any problem and see the password in plain text.

However, when I try to open the file programatically I get EACCES (Permission denied) error. That happens even though my app is running as 'system' user (I define android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in the manifest), the app is signed with the system private key and pushed into /system/app.

I know for a fact that it can be done using system permissions, because in Android's source code, in frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfigStore.java there's a code that reads this file. This code runs under the 'system_server' process, which is using the 'system' user, just like my app.

My code to open the file that fails:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(SUPPLICANT_CONFIG_FILE));
```

If both apps run with the 'system' user and have system permissions, how come system_server can read this file and my app fails? What am I missing?

Please do not suggest solutions that rely on root access, since it's irrelevant in my case. I need a solution that is based on system permissions only, not root.

Comment: More info I found out: it seems that 'system' user cannot read this file, only 'wifi' user can. However, on ps it shows that system_server is running under 'system' user, and is still able to read the file. So my guess is that system_server somehow impersonates to 'wifi' user, but I don't see any piece of code that hints on that.

Comment: Since Android is actually Linux, it may do things the same way. `wifi` may be a `group` to which the user `system` belongs, rather than being a full proper user....that doesn't help solve your problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need platform signature, add android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" property in manifest section, and add android:process="system" property in application section.

Comment: I already do that, my app runs with system user permissions. That's not the problem.

Comment: Only system signature don't solve the problem, you need add android:process="system". I've tested on AOSP 4.2.0-4.4.4

Comment: Ok, I get the difference now. Will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: That's working! Thank you so much. I would vote you up if I had enough reputation ;)