# Can I connect a wifi only one time?

Tags: java, android, wifi, wifimanager

I connect wifi programmatically in my app like that

```
private void WPA(String networkSSID, String networkPass, WifiManager wifiManager, String command) {
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wc.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
    wc.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    if (command.equals(ADD)) {
        addNetwork(wifiManager, wc);
    } else if (command.equals(REMOVE)) {
        removeNetwork(wifiManager, wc);
    }

}

private void addNetwork(WifiManager wifiManager, WifiConfiguration wc) {
    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) enableWifi();
    int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
    if (id > -1) {
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    }
}
```

I want to know if it's possible in Android to connect a wifi without saving password that when wifi is disconnected, user can not connect again without entering password? If it is possible, how can I do that programmatically?

Comment: I think you need to find out where the password is saved in the android for a wifi connection and then just clear that using your program.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post [how to extract wifi pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758650/extracting-ssid-password-from-supplicant-config-file-in-android)

and then modify it in your program to remove the desired config and save it back.